# Why do domestic electric oven do not use thermal insulation?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Domestic ovens doesn't have any form of thermal insulation AFIK, and even have vents to circulate fresh air.

[image: domestic electric oven]

It would be more energy efficient to add thermal insulation to prevent heat escaping from oven. As a second benefit, it will be reach temp faster, reducing cooking times.

So, why doesn't anybody does this?

Comment: @Andyaka. I was looking for an explanation like. "Thermostats are too slow. An insulated oven is too fast. Temp in incontrolable. You need a thermocouple + MCU + SSR to really react in time. Too expensive"

Comment: Cost..these things are cheap as dirt.... at least to manufacture, with very little profit margin.

Comment: If you're talking about microwaves, they don't heat up air to cook your food, but they warm up objects present within the microwave itself, which is why they wouldn't really benefit from insulation.

Comment: The premise of this question is simply wrong. There's nothing to salvage here: these things *are* isolated. If you can cook something on the inside at 200°C and can still put a pot of water atop of them without it starting to cook relatively soon: They *must* be isolated. And really, they are.

Comment: I had to take my oven apart (only a bit...) and it has insulation beteeen the two walls ... As has been pointed out : quality : its DeDeitrich...

Comment: As far as you know?  What evidence do you have that domestic ovens don't have any form of thermal insulation?   Do foreign ovens have insulation?

Comment: @Andyaka The essence of the question is the thermal insulation and not the electronics! This question is ontopic!

Comment: This is a question of economics, not engineering.  Countertop "ovens" must be small and also cheap, since anyone with a reasonable budget will buy a real (slide-in, big enough for Thanksgiving turkey) oven.   The cost of squeezing decent insulation into a small package like this is significant, and worse, visible to the consumer; the small increase cost in total electrical energy used is invisible to the consumer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You do know isolated and insulated are different?

Comment: That’s a toaster oven. Mine is shocking at retaining heat & I can see gaps between the internal metal sheets. What can I do to (safely) improve its efficiency?

Comment: @hazzey That answer converted to comment would have been more effective to have been posted as a new question given the "real" intent of the poster.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a very cheap oven - you can see the door is just a piece of glass (presumably heat resistant) with no seals to keep heat in.  Compare that with a decent quality oven.  Everything about this says “cheap”.  As is usually the case, better, more efficient designs usually cost more to make.  But with that said, I don’t know that anyone can really say it doesn’t have insulation without taking it apart and looking.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very cheap toaster oven, and does what it's built to do: heat things up.

Many construction workers and field technicians use it. It is cheap so that after receiving the abuse of harsh job sites and rarely if ever getting cleaned, it is rather easy to throw away and get a new one.

Comment: sorry, it's throw!

Comment: typos and predictive text grrr.... !

Answer (score 1):

It almost certainly has fiberglass insulation between the metal walls, and the vents on the **outside** that you see are there to keep the electrics relatively cool.

Answer (score 0):

Your photo shows a microwave oven. These heat the food directly using, as the name suggests, microwaves.

If you boil a cup of water in a microwave oven and then feel the walls of the inside of the oven you will find that they are not hot. Therefore there is no point in insulating them.

> [comment] I thinks it's a standard 'toaster oven' beloved by students and efficiency dwellers.

I've never used on but if the elements are on top it suggests that the food is cooked by direct infrared radiation rather than by heating the walls and air as in a baking oven. Maybe a student can answer.

Comment: I thinks it's a standard 'toaster oven' beloved by students and efficiency dwellers...

Comment: I can see the heat elements on top, it's a toaster oven!

Comment: Has anybody ever met an 'efficiency dweller'?

Comment: @Petrichor yes. Look up "micro-studio living" or "closet apartment living" or something similar.

Comment: This is definitely a toaster, not a microwave. As pointed out, there are heating coils (infrared microwaves don't look like that), which instantly proves that it's not a microwave. Further, look at the knobs. They are specific to toaster functionality. Plus, look at all the metal inside of it! Lastly, food items like that usually ask for an oven, not a microwave, and if you DO use a microwave, they wouldn't look like that. Granted, it's definitely a staged photo

Answer (score 0):

Several considerations:

- Cost
- Space: adding insulation makes the oven bigger on the outside or takes away space inside (if it shall fit into the same size cupboards an a non-insulated oven)
- You can't seal an oven hermetically, vapors need to escape anyway

I think no. 2 is the biggest consideration. A typical domestic oven (with some insulation) will fit into an 60 cm slot in your kitchen and fits a 47 cm baking tray. How many cupcakes will fit into the oven on you picture, if you remove 7 cm on both sides?